# How do I start the digital camera wizard to download pictures?

Tags: windows-7, camera

I want to download some pictures from my digital camera, but I don't know how to start the wizard. (autorun features are turn off). I tryed to run wiaacmgr.exe but it tells me to "install a scanner and try scanning again".

can anyone tell me how to start the camera wizard

thanks

Comment: Can you able to see the Camera under My Computer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found by mistake that ACDSee Photo manager (v11) has a similar tool, just press Alt+G. It has a future that I was searching for (download pics from camera with the original name, plus it has a rename template and more)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Click Start button -> Run

```
%systemdrive%\Windows\System32\control.exe /name Microsoft.ScannersAndCameras
```

It should start the Scanner and Camera wizard.